# Collecting map coordinates via using an array then plotting with MKPolyLine

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm a newbie when it comes to programming IOS devices and I need a little help.  I'm trying to create an array that will store GPS coordinates as a drive from point a to point b then I want to plot them on a map using MKPolyLine..  If someone could just give me some pointers I would greatly appreciate it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make an NSMutableArray of location coordinates (lat, long) like this:

```
[arrayOfDesc addObject:[
                        [CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude longitude:location.coordinate.longitude]];
```

and then use classes from this [source code](http://navarra.ca/?p=786). use 'NVPolylineAnnotation' and 'NVPolylineAnnotationView' classes. and pass your array through a method:

```
NVPolylineAnnotation *annotations = [[NVPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithPoints:arrayOfDesc mapView:_mapView];
[_mapView addAnnotation:annotations];
```

Its is really simple, you just need to pass the coordinates to the classes, the mentioned classes do the rest :)